# What are some way to have a "theme or design selector" in vueJs

Tags: html, mongodb, vue.js, express

I am currently working on a project for a restaurant menu page. The system should have different restaurants so I save their products data in MongoDB. I use vueJs as my frontend for the menu page (Nuxtjs will be for the client dashboard) and ExpressJs for my backend.

Each restaurant should be apple to select a design or request a design of its own. So I am assuming a different HTML code for each design but they all accept dynamic data.

What is the best place to save the HTML code? Do I have HTML files saved somewhere and then save the HTML file name in the database?

And also how do I use these designs?

I have come across these, but some people said it's bad to do it like that.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-v-runtime-template
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML

Comment: The content and the structure will change or just how it looks? If is just how it looks I'll have a base template without layout styling and different layouts and css templates depending of the restaurant

Comment: I would make the styles dynamic, and maybe render the frontend (html) of each using Js, with customisable colours, which the restaurant owners can pick themselves. Just as @larizzatg suggested , there should be base-template over which the user can make changes and design their own or make it their own